# Como establecer dos conexiones a bases de datos mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estimados tengo la siguiente clase en php para poder realizar las conexiones a mysql mediante PDO en localhost , funciona correctamente, pero me gustaria utilizar el mismo codigo pero con la opcion de poder pasarle como parametro la base de datos a la que me voy a concetar , en este caso tengo dos bases de datos y por el momento con 1 conexion funciona perfectamente, adjunto los codigos.

bd.php

```
<?php
/*Datos de conexion a la base de datos*/
define('DB_SERVIDOR', 'localhost');//DB_HOST:  generalmente suele ser "127.0.0.1"
define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');//Usuario de tu base de datos
define('DB_CLAVE', '');//Contraseña del usuario de la base de datos
define('DB_PORTAL', 'basedatos1|');//Nombre de la base de datos
define('DB_ADMIN' , 'basedatos2');
```

conexion.php

```
<?php include 'bd.php';
class Conexion {
    
    public $conexion;
    
    
    public function __construct(){
        try {
        // Conectar
            $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVIDOR.";dbname=".DB_PORTAL, DB_USUARIO, DB_CLAVE);
        // Establecer el nivel de errores a EXCEPTION
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conexion->query('SET NAMES utf8');
            $this->conexion->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
            
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }   
    
    public function obtenerdatos($datos,$tabla,$condiciones,$conjunto) {
        $query = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT $datos FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones");
        $query->execute($conjunto);
        $datos = $query->fetchALL();
        return $datos;
    }       

}

?>
```

Y desde algun otro archivo para realizar una consulta lo hago asi

```
<?php 
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/conexion/conexion.php';
$con = new Conexion();  
$datos = $con->obtenerdatos("creditos","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($parametro));       

?>
```

Comment: Porque no pasas los valores como parametros?

Comment: A que valores te refieres ? , a los valores de las consultas o pasar como valores la base datos que quiero consultar ? , porque lo ultimo es lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Los valores de la base de datos

Comment: Si las dos conexiones son al mismo servidor mejor haz: `$con->obtenerdatos("creditos",DB_PORTAL.".usuarios","idusuario = ?",array(...))`

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon ¿Ambas bases de datos van a estar siempre en el mismo servidor o vas a necesitar usar distintos host, user y pass para conectarte?

Comment: Van a estar en el mismo servidor, y se utilizará un solo usuario y contraseña

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el unico valor que cambia es el nombre de la base de datos, puedes pasarlo como parametro al constructor asi:

```
<?php include 'bd.php';
class Conexion {
    
    public $conexion;
    public $dbname;
    
    public function __construct($dbname){
        try {
        // Conectar
            $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$dbname, DB_USUARIO, DB_CLAVE);
        // Establecer el nivel de errores a EXCEPTION
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conexion->query('SET NAMES utf8');
            $this->conexion->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
            
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }   
    
    public function obtenerdatos($datos,$tabla,$condiciones,$conjunto) {
        $query = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT $datos FROM $tabla WHERE $condiciones");
        $query->execute($conjunto);
        $datos = $query->fetchALL();
        return $datos;
    }       

}

?>
```

Y luego para crear diferentes conexiones:

```
<?php 
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/conexion/conexion.php';
$con1 = new Conexion(DB_PORTAL);  
$con2 = new Conexion(DB_ADMIN);  
$datos = $con1->obtenerdatos("creditos","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($parametro));       

?>
```

Comment: Genio, me sirvio a la perfección tu respuesta, muchas gracias estimado.